# Source code that actually handles pyplot.grid() function?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to trace the code to find out which part of matplotlib source code handles this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
...
plt.grid(b=True, which='minor', color='#000000', linestyle='--')
```

I found this: https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/_modules/matplotlib/pyplot.html#grid

but it just returns `gca()` and I can't find which code in the source code actually sets the minor gridline color to `#000000` and it's linestyle to `--`.

`gca` returns `gcf` here: https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/master/lib/matplotlib/pyplot.py#L2204

And that returns `figure` but at that point I get lost and can't find the source code that sets the minor grid line styles when the `plt.grid()` function is called.

(I do know / believe that the source code that handles changing major grid line styles through rcParams can be found here: https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/master/lib/matplotlib/axes/_axes.py)

Thanks!

Comment: `Axes` inherits from [_AxesBase](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/master/lib/matplotlib/axes/_base.py#L364) and it has function [grid](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/master/lib/matplotlib/axes/_base.py#L2796) - but is runs `xaxis.grid()` and `yaxis.grid()` so you have to search deeper - [XAxis](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/master/lib/matplotlib/axis.py#L1811) and `YAxis`

Comment: @furas hm ok this is getting a bit deep. I'm looking at `XAxis` but can't see where it takes into account and sets the grid line `color` and `linestyle` in accordance with the arguments passed to `plt.grid()` :/

Comment: there is [XAxis.grid()](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/master/lib/matplotlib/axis.py#L1350) which sends `color` and `linestyle` as `kwargs` to [XAxis.set_tick_params](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/master/lib/matplotlib/axis.py#L798) and it seems it set it in dictionary [self._major_tick_kw](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/master/lib/matplotlib/axis.py#L688). BTW: In all functions it sends `color` and `linestyle` as `kwargs`